# Serializing forms into custom objects

Tags: php, serialization, laravel

I have a form:

```
<form...>
    <input type="text" name="Name" />
    <input type="text" name="Age" />
</form>
```

This data is posted to my controller:

```
...
public function PostCreatePerson()
{
    $data = Input::all();
    // I end up with an array
}
...
```

Now imagine, rather than having an array... or an array simply cast to a stdClass... I want to cast it to an custom object

```
...
public function PostCreatePerson()
{
    $data = (Person)Input::all();
    // I end up with a Person
}
...
```

**Q: Are there any frameworks that have this serialization process as a nice little function? Or am I stuck with having to map it myself? Even more specifically, is there one built into Laravel?**

```
...
public function PostCreatePerson()
{
    $person = new Person();
    $person->Name = Input::get( "Name" );
    $person->Age = Input::get( "Age" );
}
...
```

This question comes from the fact that in C#.NET MVC, the form posts its data to a controller, and the framework serializes the data into the object type that is in the controller... and I quite like that syntax.

```
...
public void PostCreatePerson( Person person )
{
    // person is of type Person and pre-mapped from the form data
}
...
```

---

---

**I've done some more experimenting...**

If I take a look at the raw posted data:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

It looks like this:

```
Name=James&Age=25
```

If I look at a serialized object:

```
$serialized = serialize( new Person() );
```

it looks like this:

```
O:6:"Person":2:{s:4:"Name";N;s:3:"Age";N;}
```

If there was a framework that asked the controller method, what type are you looking for?

```
public function PostCreatePerson( Person $person )
{...
```

And then says, oh hangon... "Person" matches the type "Person", so this is what I need to map into.

Once mapped:

```
O:6:"Person":2:{s:4:"Name";s:5:"James";s:3:"Age";i:25;}
```

It de-serializes it and injects it into the property that wanted it.

Then your form has successfully been mapped into a custom class...

I wonder if there is a framework or plugin that does this?

I only toyed with the idea of changing the serialization string to have values because then it would not call the construct of Person... Perhaps having a choice of calling or not calling the construct is a valid requirement too?

Comment: Any reason to close this? Perhaps I can expand upon my question although I think I was thorough?

Comment: What exactly is it your trying to accomplish after serializing it? If your purpose is to simply save it to the database, then Razors answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

you can set a bunch of parameters at once by:

```
$person = new Person(Input::only('Name','Age'));
```

To deal with [mass assignment](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment), you need to define fillable attributes:

```
class Person extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('Name', 'Age');

}
```

Comment: I like this because you get to keep your construct too.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just loop through your Input and map them to your model like follows. Passing the instance of the model would allow you to use it within:

```
public function PostCreatePerson() {

    $person = new Person();

    $data = Input::only('Name', 'Age');

    foreach ($data as $field => $val) {
      $person->{$field} = $val;
    }

    $person->save();

}
```

Obviously you would validate you had the correct fields before trying to save them.

*OR If you simply meaning assigning them to an object and  you could always use:*

```
public function PostCreatePerson() {

    $person = new stdClass();

    $data = Input::only('Name', 'Age');

    foreach ($data as $field => $val) {
      $person->{$field} = $val;
    }
}
```

This would allow you to access your fields like: $person->Name

Comment: Where does the Person $person come from? It's not magically posted from the form into this parameter... It will say, $person is expected instance of type Person, none given...

However, yes looping over will map the object fine, I had wondered if there is a Laravel framework or alike that will do this for me, with all the nitty gritty things you come across, already sorted out.